# Reducing the height of my div element contiuned

Tags: html, css

I am now embedded the style tag into my CSS and have also added max-height:90% as suggested but the div element is still overflowing into other elements. what am I doing wrong???

Comment: You are doing wrong that you dont provide us some code, a fiddle so that we can help you

Comment: Following up on @Mooseman's note, you'd be better off modifying your original question in response to people's comments instead of creating a new question.

Comment: opening multiple questions is silly. try to improve your previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Hard without any part of your code... but still possible to guide you a bit
You can use css overflow proprety:

```
MYELEMENT{
  overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

or

```
MYELEMENT{
  overflow-y : auto;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this also the div content still overflows...I don't know what I am doing wrong???

Comment: Can we have some code in jsfiddle.net plz ?